# How can I find website link like with regex

Tags: c#, regex

HI

I want regex option that find website links like here :

```
www.yahoo.com
yahoo.com
http://www.yahoo.com
http://yahoo.com
yahoo.jp ( or any domain)
http://yahoo.fr
```

is there anyway to track them all with regex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex from daringfireball.net should be able to do most what you want. I'm unsure about `domain.tld` since that is very ambiguous.

```
(?xi)
\b
(                           # Capture 1: entire matched URL
  (?:
    [a-z][\w-]+:                # URL protocol and colon
    (?:
      /{1,3}                        # 1-3 slashes
      |                             #   or
      [a-z0-9%]                     # Single letter or digit or '%'
                                    # (Trying not to match e.g. "URI::Escape")
    )
    |                           #   or
    www\d{0,3}[.]               # "www.", "www1.", "www2." … "www999."
    |                           #   or
    [a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/  # looks like domain name followed by a slash
  )
  (?:                           # One or more:
    [^\s()<>]+                      # Run of non-space, non-()<>
    |                               #   or
    \(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)  # balanced parens, up to 2 levels
  )+
  (?:                           # End with:
    \(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)  # balanced parens, up to 2 levels
    |                                   #   or
    [^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]        # not a space or one of these punct chars
  )
)
```

For more specifics about what it does check out http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

Comment: I used that , wand works find .
but a bit problem,
how can I find returned texts ?

I used 

MatchCollection mc18 = Regex.Matches(text, regexOption, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

what should I do know to find texts ?

regards

Comment: Are you looking to replace these occurrences or do you simply wish to find them?

Comment: also a question how can I track that if the link is between {}

like 
{ www.yahooo.com }
or {www.yahooo.com}

regards

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to throw out an alternative here, not RegEx at all.  Take a look at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), your case would look like this:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm");
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href, 'yahoo')]"])
{
  var href = link["href"];
  //href is a url that contains the word `yahoo`, do something with it
}
```

It's not really *answering* the question as you've written is, just something to keep your options open, as [RegEx can have many other problems when applied against HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).